Breaking and entering vs trespassing
Scenario:

A person is caught on the roof of a building without having any prior authorization to be there.
When asked to leave by security/building personnel he complies.
Security reports to the police that they are confused on how he got on the roof as access to it is locked, and when police search there are no burglary tools or signs of a forced entry.
The suspect doesn't volunteer any information or answer questions.

Is this Trespassing or Breaking & Entering?

A little more investigation is needed. That would not answer either one definitively.

Is the first "they" different than the second "they"?  It seems that way from context, but you should clarify...  And did they get "in" the building, or were they just "on" the roof?

@MichaelHall The first they is the person caught on the roof. The second they is the security/building personnel

OK, I tried to clarify the scenario with an edit, please let me know if it remains try to your intent...

Where I live, climbing over a fence makes you guilty of breaking and entering IFF all of the gates through the fence are locked. IDK what the judge would say about climbing up the side of a building, but it seems like there is some similarity between the two.

This question is unclear about some key details like the nature of the building and what the person was actually doing there. We try to provide answers at Law.SE based upon whether or not the law was violated, not whether or not the suspect is likely to be caught or punished.

@Ohm'sLawman In the scenario the suspect isn't climbing up the side of the building just using the door to get to the roof.

@ohwilleke Lets say photography. The suspect didn't commit any crimes further after they got past the door. No burglary or vandalism happened.

@JuicySeals So the motive makes is not burglary, but using the door to get to the roof probably does make it criminal trespass.

Florida law makes a number of distinctions the depend upon the nature of the property. I assume a residence, but the question isn't clear what kind of structure is involved. There are half a dozen or so special rules in Florida law that depend upon the type of the structure.
Trespassing involves being on the property of another without permission. While an implied license is assumed to walk up to a front door, this limitation wouldn't apply in the case of being on a roof. But, being told to leave and not promptly leaving is an offense.
Florida has several trespass laws, some applicable to public property or caves, and another pertaining to being inside a structure, which do not apply. The most relevant Florida statute states:

810.09 Trespass on property other than structure or conveyance.—
(1)(a) A person who, without being authorized, licensed, or invited,
willfully enters upon or remains in any property other than a
structure or conveyance:
1. As to which notice against entering or remaining is given, either by actual communication to the offender or by posting, fencing, or
cultivation as described in s. 810.011; or
2. If the property is the unenclosed curtilage of a dwelling and the offender enters or remains with the intent to commit an offense
thereon, other than the offense of trespass, commits the offense of
trespass on property other than a structure or conveyance.
(b) As used in this section, the term “unenclosed curtilage” means the
unenclosed land or grounds, and any outbuildings, that are directly
and intimately adjacent to and connected with the dwelling and
necessary, convenient, and habitually used in connection with that
dwelling.
(2)(a) Except as provided in this subsection, trespass on property
other than a structure or conveyance is a misdemeanor of the first
degree, punishable as provided in s. 775.082 or s. 775.083.
(b) If the offender defies an order to leave, personally communicated
to the offender by the owner of the premises or by an authorized
person, or if the offender willfully opens any door, fence, or gate or
does any act that exposes animals, crops, or other property to waste,
destruction, or freedom; unlawfully dumps litter on property; or
trespasses on property other than a structure or conveyance, the
offender commits a misdemeanor of the first degree, punishable as
provided in s. 775.082 or s. 775.083.
(c) If the offender is armed with a firearm or other dangerous weapon
during the commission of the offense of trespass on property other
than a structure or conveyance, he or she is guilty of a felony of the
third degree, punishable as provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s.
775.084. Any owner or person authorized by the owner may, for prosecution purposes, take into custody and detain, in a reasonable
manner, for a reasonable length of time, any person when he or she
reasonably believes that a violation of this paragraph has been or is
being committed, and that the person to be taken into custody and
detained has committed or is committing the violation. If a person is
taken into custody, a law enforcement officer shall be called as soon
as is practicable after the person has been taken into custody. The
taking into custody and detention in compliance with the requirements
of this paragraph does not result in criminal or civil liability for
false arrest, false imprisonment, or unlawful detention.
(d) The offender commits a felony of the third degree, punishable as
provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if the property
trespassed is a construction site that is:
1. Greater than 1 acre in area and is legally posted and identified in substantially the following manner: “THIS AREA IS A DESIGNATED
CONSTRUCTION SITE, AND ANYONE WHO TRESPASSES ON THIS PROPERTY COMMITS
A FELONY.”; or
2. One acre or less in area and is identified as such with a sign that appears prominently, in letters of not less than 2 inches in height,
and reads in substantially the following manner: “THIS AREA IS A
DESIGNATED CONSTRUCTION SITE, AND ANYONE WHO TRESPASSES ON THIS
PROPERTY COMMITS A FELONY.” The sign shall be placed at the location
on the property where the permits for construction are located. For
construction sites of 1 acre or less as provided in this subparagraph,
it shall not be necessary to give notice by posting as defined in s.
810.011(5).
(e) The offender commits a felony of the third degree, punishable as
provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if the property
trespassed upon is commercial horticulture property and the property
is legally posted and identified in substantially the following
manner: “THIS AREA IS DESIGNATED COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR HORTICULTURE
PRODUCTS, AND ANYONE WHO TRESPASSES ON THIS PROPERTY COMMITS A
FELONY.”
(f) The offender commits a felony of the third degree, punishable as
provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if the property
trespassed upon is an agricultural site for testing or research
purposes that is legally posted and identified in substantially the
following manner: “THIS AREA IS A DESIGNATED AGRICULTURAL SITE FOR
TESTING OR RESEARCH PURPOSES, AND ANYONE WHO TRESPASSES ON THIS
PROPERTY COMMITS A FELONY.”
(g) The offender commits a felony of the third degree, punishable as
provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if the property
trespassed upon is a domestic violence center certified under s.
39.905 which is legally posted and identified in substantially the following manner: “THIS AREA IS A DESIGNATED RESTRICTED SITE AND
ANYONE WHO TRESPASSES ON THIS PROPERTY COMMITS A FELONY.”
(h) Any person who in taking or attempting to take any animal
described in s. 379.101(19) or (20), or in killing, attempting to
kill, or endangering any animal described in s. 585.01(13) knowingly
propels or causes to be propelled any potentially lethal projectile
over or across private land without authorization commits trespass, a
felony of the third degree, punishable as provided in s. 775.082, s.
775.083, or s. 775.084. For purposes of this paragraph, the term “potentially lethal projectile” includes any projectile launched from
any firearm, bow, crossbow, or similar tensile device. This section
does not apply to any governmental agent or employee acting within the
scope of his or her official duties.
(i) The offender commits a felony of the third degree, punishable as
provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if the property
trespassed upon is an agricultural chemicals manufacturing facility
that is legally posted and identified in substantially the following
manner: “THIS AREA IS A DESIGNATED AGRICULTURAL CHEMICALS
MANUFACTURING FACILITY, AND ANYONE WHO TRESPASSES ON THIS PROPERTY
COMMITS A FELONY.”
(j)1. The offender commits a felony of the third degree, punishable as
provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if the offender
trespasses with the intent to injure another person, damage property,
or impede the operation or use of an aircraft, runway, taxiway, ramp,
or apron area, and the property trespassed upon is the operational
area of an airport that is legally posted and identified in
substantially the following manner: “THIS AREA IS A DESIGNATED
OPERATIONAL AREA OF AN AIRPORT AND ANYONE WHO TRESPASSES ON THIS
PROPERTY COMMITS A FELONY.”
2. For purposes of this paragraph, the term “operational area of an airport” means any portion of an airport to which access by the public
is prohibited by fences or appropriate signs and includes runways,
taxiways, ramps, apron areas, aircraft parking and storage areas, fuel
storage areas, maintenance areas, and any other area of an airport
used or intended to be used for landing, takeoff, or surface
maneuvering of aircraft.
(3) As used in this section, the term “authorized person” or “person
authorized” means any owner, his or her agent, or a community
association authorized as an agent for the owner, or any law
enforcement officer whose department has received written
authorization from the owner, his or her agent, or a community
association authorized as an agent for the owner, to communicate an
order to leave the property in the case of a threat to public safety
or welfare.

The language in bold is the "entering" part of breaking and entering. The breaking part would be among other things criminal mischief (a.k.a. vandalism). In this case there is neither entering within the meaning of the trespass statute nor destruction of property within the meaning of the criminal mischief statute, so what is colloquially called breaking and entering doesn't appear to have happened.
Of course, it is possible that the suspect got into his position with other illegal acts that law enforcement hasn't figured out yet. Indeed, the circumstances strongly suggest that some other crime was intended or committed to get in that position, although there isn't enough detail in the question to know (and generally speaking, we try to provide answers at Law.SE about whether someone was actually violating the law and not whether law enforcement will be competent enough to prove it).
This might also be a case of attempted burglary, but one would first have to be able to prove, with circumstantial evidence, why the suspect was on the roof, and show that it was with an intent to commit a crime.
As shown below, burglary generally requires that you be "in" the structure, which it isn't obvious that being on a rooftop satisfies.
The Florida burglary statue states:

810.02 Burglary.—
(1)(a) For offenses committed on or before July 1, 2001, “burglary”
means entering or remaining in a dwelling, a structure, or a
conveyance with the intent to commit an offense therein, unless the
premises are at the time open to the public or the defendant is
licensed or invited to enter or remain.
(b) For offenses committed after July 1, 2001, “burglary” means:
1. Entering a dwelling, a structure, or a conveyance with the intent to commit an offense therein, unless the premises are at the time open
to the public or the defendant is licensed or invited to enter; or
2. Notwithstanding a licensed or invited entry, remaining in a dwelling, structure, or conveyance:
a. Surreptitiously, with the intent to commit an offense therein;
b. After permission to remain therein has been withdrawn, with the
intent to commit an offense therein; or
c. To commit or attempt to commit a forcible felony, as defined in s.
776.08.
(2) Burglary is a felony of the first degree, punishable by
imprisonment for a term of years not exceeding life imprisonment or as
provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if, in the course
of committing the offense, the offender:
(a) Makes an assault or battery upon any person; or
(b) Is or becomes armed within the dwelling, structure, or conveyance,
with explosives or a dangerous weapon; or
(c) Enters an occupied or unoccupied dwelling or structure, and:
1. Uses a motor vehicle as an instrumentality, other than merely as a getaway vehicle, to assist in committing the offense, and thereby
damages the dwelling or structure; or
2. Causes damage to the dwelling or structure, or to property within the dwelling or structure in excess of $1,000.
(3) Burglary is a felony of the second degree, punishable as provided
in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if, in the course of
committing the offense, the offender does not make an assault or
battery and is not and does not become armed with a dangerous weapon
or explosive, and the offender enters or remains in a:
(a) Dwelling, and there is another person in the dwelling at the time
the offender enters or remains;
(b) Dwelling, and there is not another person in the dwelling at the
time the offender enters or remains;
(c) Structure, and there is another person in the structure at the
time the offender enters or remains;
(d) Conveyance, and there is another person in the conveyance at the
time the offender enters or remains;
(e) Authorized emergency vehicle, as defined in s. 316.003; or
(f) Structure or conveyance when the offense intended to be committed
therein is theft of a controlled substance as defined in s. 893.02.
Notwithstanding any other law, separate judgments and sentences for
burglary with the intent to commit theft of a controlled substance
under this paragraph and for any applicable possession of controlled
substance offense under s. 893.13 or trafficking in controlled
substance offense under s. 893.135 may be imposed when all such
offenses involve the same amount or amounts of a controlled substance.
However, if the burglary is committed during a riot or an aggravated
riot prohibited under s. 870.01 and the perpetration of the burglary
is facilitated by conditions arising from the riot; or within a county
that is subject to a state of emergency declared by the Governor under
chapter 252 after the declaration of emergency is made and the
perpetration of the burglary is facilitated by conditions arising from
the emergency, the burglary is a felony of the first degree,
punishable as provided in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084. As
used in this subsection, the term “conditions arising from the riot”
means civil unrest, power outages, curfews, or a reduction in the
presence of or response time for first responders or homeland security
personnel and the term “conditions arising from the emergency” means
civil unrest, power outages, curfews, voluntary or mandatory
evacuations, or a reduction in the presence of or response time for
first responders or homeland security personnel. A person arrested for
committing a burglary during a riot or an aggravated riot or within a
county that is subject to such a state of emergency may not be
released until the person appears before a committing magistrate at a
first appearance hearing. For purposes of sentencing under chapter
921, a felony offense that is reclassified under this subsection is
ranked one level above the ranking under s. 921.0022 or s. 921.0023 of
the offense committed.
(4) Burglary is a felony of the third degree, punishable as provided
in s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084, if, in the course of
committing the offense, the offender does not make an assault or
battery and is not and does not become armed with a dangerous weapon
or explosive, and the offender enters or remains in a:
(a) Structure, and there is not another person in the structure at the
time the offender enters or remains; or
(b) Conveyance, and there is not another person in the conveyance at
the time the offender enters or remains. However, if the burglary is
committed during a riot or an aggravated riot prohibited under s.
870.01 and the perpetration of the burglary is facilitated by conditions arising from the riot; or within a county that is subject
to a state of emergency declared by the Governor under chapter 252
after the declaration of emergency is made and the perpetration of the
burglary is facilitated by conditions arising from the emergency, the
burglary is a felony of the second degree, punishable as provided in
s. 775.082, s. 775.083, or s. 775.084. As used in this subsection, the
terms “conditions arising from the riot” and “conditions arising from
the emergency” have the same meanings as provided in subsection (3). A
person arrested for committing a burglary during a riot or an
aggravated riot or within a county that is subject to such a state of
emergency may not be released until the person appears before a
committing magistrate at a first appearance hearing. For purposes of
sentencing under chapter 921, a felony offense that is reclassified
under this subsection is ranked one level above the ranking under s.
921.0022 or s. 921.0023 of the offense committed.

For example, if he was trying to parachute into his own backyard in the neighborhood, but got carried onto the roof by a gust of wind, and then the parachute blew away before law enforcement arrived, it wouldn't be attempted burglary, or breaking and entering. Trespass liability in that fact pattern would depend upon the level of intent required for criminal trespass in Florida law. Florida requires enough intent that this would probably not be a crime.

You are confused as to what breaking and entering is. Most places do not have a law titled that. It is used to enhance burglary or other offenses, being that a break in occured making the offense more serious.

that is nowhere close to being true. What state are you basing that on?

Most places have a breaking and entering offense. But at the state level at least, it seems that it is dealt with in the burglary and trespass statutes (and probably vandalism statutes as well).

@Mimedfp, You are arguing with an extremely credible and prolific contributor here.  I am confident he is correct, and the link I posted in the comment on your answer solidifies this...

Where I live, walking up to the front door is trespassing, but mere trespassing is not a crime. Where I live, you are guilty of unlawful trespassing if you walk on somebody's property after they have asked you to keep off of it. They can ask you to your face, or they can ask you by sending a letter, or they can "ask" you by posting signs that meet a certain standard of visibility at certain intervals around the perimeter of the property. (In places near to where I live, they can "ask" by painting purple, horizontal stripes around tree trunks at the perimeter of the property.)

Your comment lists a definition so it is wrong by default. Charges are brought under a law.

@ohwilleke you were wrong.

@Mimedfp Under Florida law (which I thought was part of the question originally) I'm wrong about the name of the offense. But many, many U.S. jurisdictions do have a breaking and entering offense.

You are wrong about more than the name. It is the idea of making the crime more serious because there was a break in, as I said.

@ohwilleke Let's say the structure is a public building like a hotel or office building. The suspect doesn't have a reason for being at the building other than to get into the roof.

Breaking and entering usually refers to a burglary or other crime that was committed after the person broke in. It is often used as a catchall phrase.
Trespassing usually means a person was asked to leave and is there.
Being on the roof does not say that either of those things occured.

@MichaelHall that is not true. Breaking and entering is usually a name for whatever offense covers breaking in and stealing.

Many jurisdictions do not have an offense titled Breaking and Entering. It is used as a catchall phrase.

You are just wrong. Burglary as distinct from breaking and entering, involves entering into property without permission with intent to commit a crime. Breaking and entering is usually a separate and lesser offense.

"Breaking and entering is defined as the entering of a building through force without authorization."  Source:  https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/breaking_and_entering

@MichaelHall right, but that is not a specific state statute. You bring charges under a law.

And I am just as confident that there is a law somewhere against breaking and entering as you are certain that there isn't.

Produce the law then.

Would it help to edit the question to eliminate B&E to replace with Burglary? Actually I won't, because doing so would invalidate ohwilleke's answer...

His answer is wrong. There is no real answer based on the question. Being somewhere is not inherently illegal is the point.

You can "break into" and "enter" an outdoor space that is enclosed by a fence. Where I live, you can be found guilty of breaking and entering even if you didn't actually "break" anything (e.g., if all you did was climb over the fence.)

It seems that this answer may be correct in FL, which is the question's jurisdiction. https://www.roelkelaw.com/practice-areas/criminal-defense/property-crimes/breaking-and-entering/#:~:text=In%20Florida%2C%20all%20burglary%20charges,burglary%20and%20third%2Ddegree%20burglary.

"Produce the law then."  OK.  All it takes is one: https://www.ncleg.net/enactedlegislation/statutes/html/bysection/chapter_14/gs_14-54.html

@MichaelHall What state is that statute for (does "ncleg.net" mean North Carolina)? The question is about Florida law.

They have heard people say breaking and entering and they base it off things they have heard versus the facts of the matter.

@Barmar, yes, North Carolina.  I see the tag, but that doesn't limit the question or any answers.  Beside, my reason for posting was in response to a more general argument that there is no such charge as B&E.

You can't vote me down for saying usually when most states do not have it and vote him up when he was wrong actually is the point.

We can vote the other answer up because of its thoroughness (as is usual for ohwileke), and vote this one down because it's so terse and general that it's not very useful. Actually, people can vote up/down for whatever reason they like.

It is not really unhelpful, being that the information is right. Lol
